# expanding a (g)vim snippet from command line

Tags: vim, code-snippets

I have a snippet that expands properly from the vim insert mode:

```
#In vim insertmode, `prg will expand snippet prg in Ultisnips dir
:execute 'imap `prg prg' . g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger . '<Esc>gg=G<C-j>'
```

But I tried to use this is vim's commandline as well:

```
:execute prg . :UltiSnipsExpandTrigger
```

(**Update: removed imap**)

This is giving me error :

```
E115: Missing quote: '
E15: Invalid Expression: 'imap `prg prg' . g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger . '
```

The RHS of the menu mode is the same function that is used in insert mode. Don't know why it is complaining.

Kindly help.

Comment: Why are you adding an `imap` for a snippet? I'm not sure you are using snippets as they should (that would solve your other question). Perhaps see this: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-ultisnips/

Comment: @Laser: the imap is just for using a key-combination for the actual snippet. May be I have complicated the question, but a simple `:execute prg . g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger` is also giving the same error. 

I am attaching the snippet is http://ur1.ca/mtbog
And I am trying to expand the snippet from commandline (it works in insert mode properly), which I need for some reason.